# Azure AD B2C. ROPC flow error The application associated with client id has no registered redirect URIs

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

## The application associated with client id 09ac92da-a796-4cd9-973b-c97756____ has no registered redirect URIs

### Description

I followed the steps described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-ropc?tabs=applications.

When attempting to obtain the token in Postman using ROPC I'm getting

```
{
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "AADB2C90007: The application associated with client id '09ac92da-a796-4cd9-973b-c97756____' has no registered redirect URIs.\r\nCorrelation ID: e85003c3-cfd5-43ad-a74b-efa5c1ea6525\r\nTimestamp: 2019-12-06 19:47:42Z\r\n"
}
```

I should not be asked for a redirect URIs.

My POST is as follows:

`URL: ''https://mytenant.b2clogin.com/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token?p=B2C_1_ROPC_Auth"`

```
username: some_username_of_a_user
password: its-password
grant_type: password
scope: openid offline_access 09ac92da-a796-4cd9-973b-c97756____
client_id: 09ac92da-a796-4cd9-973b-c97756____
response-type: token id_token
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't reproduce your issue by following [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-ropc?tabs=applications). Here are the main steps for your reference.

1.Create a resource owner user flow

[image]

2.Register an application(It is an application under Azure AD B2C, not Azure AD)

[image]

3.Test the user flow

[image]

Comment: Hi Tony Ju, Thanks for your attention. It works your way! The difference with I was doing is that I followed the **App Registration (Preview)** way.

It is not working following that approach, though.

I also found a workaround using the Preview approach. You have to provide a valid redirect_uri while registering your application.

Then you have to add a redirect_uri field to the body of your request matching the one provided in-app registration.

That works but is not correct, in my opinion.

I'll address your findings and mines in the Github issue, thanks again!

Comment: @NachoVazquezCalleja My pleasure. It seems that the preview version doesn't work for ROPC flow.

Comment: Of course! I voted it but my votes are not visible bc of my reputation level.

Answer (score 0):

This error generally occurs because you still need to configure some application claims in the b2c directory user flow to allow complete access to the application.

You need to make sure that the right versions of the authentication are in the reply url (likely extension v2.0) and that the reply URL is configured in the application and in the code.

Please look to the documentation for the reply URL schema that you would need to follow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-register-applications?tabs=applications#register-a-web-application

If you still run into this issue let me know and I can reach out to the correct product team contacts, as sometimes this can happen due to breaking changes on our end.

Comment: Thanks, Marilee, for your time with this here and in Github. I'll take a second review at everything, but if there is a configuration issue, the docs should be updated. 

Docs provide an excellent description of the configurations needed, but if that is not everything needed, then docs are incomplete.

I'll keep you posted on what I found.

Thanks again!

Comment: To be clear, I'm using Resource Owner Password Credential. Therefore, no redirect Url should be necessary nor required.